# Newtonsoft JsonConvert, overwrite current IEnumerable items

Tags: .net, vb.net, json.net

I have an object that looks something like this:

```
    Public Class ExportOptions

        Public Sub New()
            CategoryIDs = {New Guid("30ndd837-7a2c-477c-b892-67f129f7af4e")}
        End Sub

        Property CategoryIDs As IEnumerable(Of Guid)

    End Class
```

I'm then deserializing the JSON like so:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of ExportOptions)(JSONString)
```

Problem is the values in the JSON are not getting into the CategoryIDs property?  Instead I'm left with just the single value that was used in the constructor.

If I change CategoryIDs to a List(of Guid) then the new categoryIDs are added to the list when I need them to overwrite the current items.

The value added in the constructor is a default value and must be there in case nothing has been passed by the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to work this out on my own in the end:-

```
            Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of AmazonSimpleExportOptions)(JSONString,
                                                                                        New Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings With {
                                                                                            .ObjectCreationHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ObjectCreationHandling.Replace})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class ExportOptions

        Private defaultGuid As New Guid("30ndd837-7a2c-477c-b892-67f129f7af4e")
        Private cats as List(Of Guid) = {defaultGuid}

        Public Sub New()

        End Sub

        Property CategoryIDs As List(Of Guid)
            Get
                Return cats
            End Get

            Set(ByVal Value As List(Of Guid))
                cats = Value
                If cats.Count = 0 Then cats.Add(defaultGuid)
            End Set
        End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks Roy, that's my current fall back solution.  Because the actually solution uses interfaces and there will be a number of these classes throughout the solution with different lists it would be nice to automate as much as possible!

Comment: @Rene147 Possible alternative if you don't want to touch the serialised classes is: instead of adding the item to a list by default, when accessing it use CategoryIDs.DefaultIfEmpty(New Guid("30ndd837-7a2c-477c-b892-67f129f7af4e"))